# rm -rf: Unix thinks '-rf' is a file not an option

Tags: mac, bash, unix, shell

I run the following command in Terminal on my OS X Snow Leopard laptop:

```
rm -rf /path/to/directory
```

Normally, this deletes the directory and all contents/subdirectories.  For some reason, though, it now gives the following error message:

```
rm: –rf: No such file or directory
rm: /path/to/directory: is a directory
```

I'd be grateful if somebody could share why rm doesn't recognize '-rf' as an option string?

Comment: Voted to move to superuser. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Answer (score 14):

In your second "code" block, you're using `–` instead of `-`.

The `–` character you're using is not the `-` ASCII character that is used to prefix command line options, therefore `–rf` is interpreted as a file name.

Use `rm -rf /path/to/directory`.

Comment: Nice catch. The character in the quoted `rm: –rf: No such file or directory` message is U+2013 EN DASH, not the normal option introducing character U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS. Probably the result of copying and pasting some overzealously re-formatted text from a web page of some sort.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

Is `rm` aliased to something? `rm` will interpret `-rf` as a file name if it somehow has `--` in the argument list, as in `rm -- -rf /path/directory`.

Try it with a backslash in front, which disables aliases. Or use the full path:

```
\rm -rf /path/directory
/bin/rm -rf /path/directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're feeding it the correct path name? If it contains spaces, make sure you include quotation marks.

```
rm -rf "/my folder/here"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a random thing to try. Have you tried:

```
rm -r -f /path/to/directory
```